# Move domain away from a host while leaving the Exchange email service unaffected

Tags: dns, domain-registration

I currently have a domain registered with Fasthosts and are using their Exchange email service on this domain.

For various reasons I would like to move the domain registration to another domain host, but I want to leave the Exchange email service on Fasthosts operational.

I know I can do it from scratch with the domain being hosted elsewhere, but I'm concerned that if I move the domain away then all associated services will be terminated.

Is there a way to do this and if so how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can transfer your domain to any other domain registrar, but you should keep the current DNS servers set on your domain, so that you can use all the current services after transfer.

If this service is bought along with domain and you don't pay for it independently, the service will be removed by transferring the domain. It's not possible to transfer your domain and keep the service this way. However, any independent service can be kept after transferring.

Comment: OK, I know I *can* do that, but my experience in the past is that when transferring a domain away that the services (exchange email) associated with the domain are automatically removed - and I can't afford to risk that if there is any chance that the exchange email will removed as well.

Comment: If this service is bought along with domain and you don't pay for it independently, the service will be removed by transferring the domain. It's not possible to transfer your domain and keep the service this way. However, any independent service can be kept after transferring.